# How to release assigned local port in JSch tunneling?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, portforwarding, tunneling

How to release assigned local port in JSch tunneling automatically after specified time or when the port is inactive?

I used the following function to achieve port forwarding:

```
session.setPortForwardingL("my.ip",9901,remote_host,1001,ssf,1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the timeout yourself and call the [`Session.delPortForwardingL`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#delPortForwardingL-int-).

---

The `connectTimeout` that you are setting in [`Session.setPortForwardingL`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html#setPortForwardingL-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-int-com.jcraft.jsch.ServerSocketFactory-int-) call is only passed to `Channel.connect(connectTimeout)` and limits how long will the code wait for the channel to open. The name (`connectTimeout`) says it after all. It has no effect whatsoever after the channel/forwarding is opened.